# What command focuses an open file in another window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If I'm in window A, and file `foo.txt` is open in window B, I want a command that works like `workbench.action.quickOpen`, but instead of opening another copy of `foo.txt` in window A, I want it to focus the `foo.txt` tab within window B. If there's no built-in command, is there an extension that provides this function?

Comment: There isn't a command for this, you have to switch windows manually.

Comment: Instead of a quick open have you tried a standard open operation (`openTextDocument(uri: Uri): Thenable<TextDocument>`)? IIRC vscode will take focus the tab with the file if it is already open.

Comment: Not sure what that is—nothing comes up when I search for it under `workbench.action.showCommands`. Do you mean `⌘-O`? That opens a new tab in the current window.